# Prevent CSS grid row heights growing with dynamic content

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to define a CSS grid, with auto-rows (a dynamic number thereof) which size to a container based only on the number of them, i.e. filling the available vertical space - and then containing any content within that vertical space.

See below, the left hand side shows the equal row height sizes assigned when the content does not cause the rows to grow.

On the right is the problem - long text causes the heights to then become unequal.

The code is at this pen:
https://codepen.io/jamesharcourt/pen/GRBdRWo

[image]

In the image above, I want the sizes to remain as per the left and the text to essentially not be visible / overflow to be hidden.

Sample css:

```
.columns {
  display: flex;
}

.content-area {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  background: pink;
}

.item {
  margin: 2px;
  background: gray;   
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="content-area">
    <div class="item">1 short text</div>
    <div class="item">2 short text</div>
    <div class="item">3 short text</div>
    <div class="item">4 short text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-area">
    <div class="item">1 short text</div>
    <div class="item">2 short text</div>
    <div class="item">3 short text</div>
    <div class="item">4 long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you looking into a masonry layout, is that correct?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  There is only one column.  In the example they are two separate layouts just for displaying working and not working.  Basically I'm asking how to keep the heights equal as per the left, even when the *content* within (which is dynamic) takes it over that height.  Stopping them from growing, in other words.

Comment: `minmax(0,1fr)` instead of `1fr` OR `overflow: auto;` to items

Comment: It is possible if all grid items were under a single parent. Unfortunately having shared layouts across separate grids is only possible using [subgrid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid) and is currently only available on Firefox & Safari.

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you, this worked but `overflow:auto` had to in this case be `overflow: hidden`